# vue.draggable distinct drop zones

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuedraggable, vue.draggable

I'm wondering if it's possible to have distinct drop zones with vue.draggable. 
What I mean is:

- I have a pile of different foods and they can be dragged to the plate zone.
- I have a pile of different drinks and they can be dragged to the cup zone.
- I have a pile of different desserts and they can be dragged to the dessert zone.

Etc.
Is there any easy way to do this with vue.draggable?